# i am trying to code in c sharp and i have a 3D array like this

Tags: c#, arrays, 3d

i am trying to code in c sharp and i have a 3D array like this:

1 7 13

3 9 15

5 11 17

here is my code:

```
 int row = 3;
            int col = 3;
            int[,] times;
            times = new int[col, row];
            string matrixstring = " ";
            int mult = -1;

            for (int j = 0; j != row; j++)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i != col; i++)
                {
                    mult = mult + 2;
                    matrixstring += mult.ToString();
                    matrixstring += " ";
                }
                    matrixstring += Environment.NewLine;
                }
                this.richTextBox1.Text = matrixstring;
```

i got output :

1  3 5

7  9 11

13 15 17

so whats the problem in my code..?

Comment: That's not a 3D array. Have you tried stepping through your code and using your debugger?

Comment: ok.. but can you tell me how can i get this output?

Comment: its still not working...

Comment: @john it would give the exact same output

Answer (score 1):

The problem with your code is, that you increase the value in the inner loop, which is building one line, by 2, so of course you get the output as you have shown it below your code.
If you want to get the output as it is at the beginning of your question, then you should increase the value in the inner loop by 6. The starting values of the lines should be increased by 2.
By the way you do not use the `times` array.
An example producing the above output:

```
        int row = 3;
        int col = 3;
        string matrixstring = "";

        for (int j = 0; j != row; j++) {
            int mult = 1+j*2;
            for (int i = 0; i != col; i++) {
                matrixstring += mult.ToString ();
                matrixstring += " ";
                mult += 6;
            }
            matrixstring += Environment.NewLine;
            this.richTextBox1.Text = matrixstring;
```

Answer (score 1):

First, in a C# 2D array the first dimension would be considered the row, the second would be the column. So i would reverse the names in the times array definition. Also, assuming you want the times array for later use, you could populate it by going down the columns first, but then pivot it by outputing the rows first. Like this:

```
int row = 3;
int col = 3;
int[,] times = new int[row, col];
int mult = -1;


for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
    for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
    {
        mult += 2;
        times[r,c] = mult;
    }

string matrixstring = "";

for (int r = 0; r < row; r++)
{
    for (int c = 0; c < col; c++)
        matrixstring += times[r,c].ToString() + " ";

    matrixstring += Environment.NewLine;
}

this.richTextBox1.Text = matrixstring;
```

Notice the order of the two for loops.